# Blazor: Read/observe query parameter from anywhere

Tags: localization, blazor

I have an existing ASP.NET Core + angular application that needs to be converted to a blazor server app due to SEO considerations.

The existing angular app monitors the `lang` query parameter and changes the ui-language accordingly. I've made a minimal reproduction [in the following repository](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/AngularI18N).

In the AppComponent the query parameter is monitored and changes the language of the entire application:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private translateService: TranslateService) {
  const defaultLang = 'en';
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
    const lang = params['lang'];
    if (!!lang) {
      this.translateService.use(lang);
    } else {
      this.translateService.use(defaultLang);
    }
  });
}
```

Now the similar behavior should be applied to the blazor application, but I can't find out how to monitor the query parameters from the `AppComponent`.

[Here is a repository with the VS solution](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/ObserveQueryParametersBlazor)

This is the code of the AppComponent, where I keep an eye on the `lang` query parameter.

```
@using System.Globalization
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
<p>Current language: @Language, @language</p>

@code {

    private string language;
    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "lang")]
    public string Language
    {
        get => language;
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Culture has been set to " + value);
            language = value;
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(value);
        }
    }
}
```

On all pages I have somewhat the following code:

```
@page "/xxx"

<p>Language: @Language</p>

@code {
    ...

    [Parameter]
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery(Name = "lang")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine. However putting the same code on the `AppComponent` does not work, since `SupplyParameterFromQuery` works only in a route context.

[image: Reading the queryparameter in blazor app component doesn't work]

How can I read+observe a query parameter anywhere in the Blazor app properly? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding the language as a `CascadinValue` in your `App.razor` and then use `[CascadingParameter]`.

Comment: Thanks, but this only seems to allow data to flow from parent to child. But I can only access the query parameters from the routing components (children)

Comment: You can inject `HttpClient` and get the URI from there...

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with the code and behavior of the angular app

Comment: Sadly I'm unable to get a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n2lbow?file=src/app/app.component.ts) working properly, but the project in the repository works fine.

Comment: I have added an answer. I hope it helps, otherwise, I will edit if I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your updated question I think I can provide a working solution.

This would be the structure of `App.razor`:

```xml
<CascadingValue Value="AppCountry">
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <Router AdditionalAssemblies="@lazyLoadedAssemblies" AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true" OnNavigateAsync="@OnNavigateAsync">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(SharedLayout.MainLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                        }
                    </NotAuthorized>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(SharedLayout.MainLayout)">
                    <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
</CascadingValue>
```

Notice the `OnNavigateAsync` event in your router component. The event should look something like this:

```cs
private async Task OnNavigateAsync(NavigationContext args)
{
   
}
```

This event fires every time you navigate through the app. You have two options:

1. Inject `HttpClient` in `App.razor` and use it to get the query parameters.
2. Use `args.Path`. This returns everything after the base address. For example for `www.example.com/index?lang=en-US` it will return `index?lang=en-US`.

Do all the necessary checks and change your Culture.

More info about globalization and localization can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly).

Comment: `OnNavigateAsync` combined with `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` seems to come close to what I want. However, I've [created a project](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/BlazorI18N) now with the `UseRequestLocalization` middleware, and it seems that the prerendered result is localized, but after webassembly kicks in, everything's in the default language again.

Comment: I get 404 when I click the link.